# New to git.. Do I always have to do a "git fetch" everything my notebook gets on network

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am new to git and I would like to know if I have to do a "git fetch" everytime my netbook gets on a network so I have the most updated version of the code from the repository.

Comment: Yes. This is a bad question. It is broad in the sense that it would require a complete explanation of DVCS systems.

Comment: "In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`." http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html

Comment: Consider just using "git remote update".

Comment: For which purpose did you clone the repository?  Are you contributing or just tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the sense that `git` will not grab changes from the remote repository unless you explicitly tell it to. No, in the sense that you don't *have* to grab those changes if you don't want to; you can run `git fetch` and merge any changes it finds at your leisure.

Comment: should I use fetch or pull??

Comment: This is a little oversimplified, but `git fetch` will get changes from the remote repository, but you have to merge them into your local branch manually with `git merge`. `git pull` combines the `fetch` and `merge` into one step.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to**, that's why it is DVCS. But if you want to get the most updated version, yes you should `pull` it from remote.

[Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: you tell me pull others tell me fetch, which one

Comment: @techsjs2013 it depends on how you want your revision graph to look.  `git pull` will fetch merge the upstream into your current branch.  That means you may have a merge commit if you introduced something locally, but hadn't pushed it for others to see yet.  If you prefer a more linear history, folks will often do a fetch, and then rebase against the upstream: `git rebase @{u}`.  `git pull` has on option you can set to rebase by default.  Folks advocating the fetch and rebase approach are interested in avoiding useless commits that pull can create.

Comment: `git pull --rebase` is always an option